# ToShortDateString is resulting Time also. How to show Date Only?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

```
DateSerial(2015, 5, 1).ToShortDateString
```

is resulting **01-05-15 12:00:00 AM**.

How do I Get it as **01-05-15**?

Using it on **GridView** Control

Comment: What's the format? mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: Just use the proper format string with ToString or String.Format. `ToShortDateString` is just a convenience method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`date.ToString("dd'-'MM'-'yyyy")`

(for explicit format, switch dd and MM according what you wish in first : day or month) or

```
date.ToString("d")
```

(culture dependant).

See here for examples : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: date.ToString("dd'-'MM'-'yyyy") Still getting the Time :(

Comment: Nevertheless my answer is good. I've seen your edit : you have added that you are binding a GridView. This is probably from where comes your problem, your ToString method is probably not called as you think. Please post all relevant parts of your code for databinding.

Comment: You're right the Gridview is the culprit in which the column is defined as Date.  Just changed it as String which works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateSerial(2015, 5, 1).ToString("dd-MM-yy")
```

use ToString method

Comment: I tried your suggestion but getting the same result with time.

Answer (score 1):

The ToString method should do the trick i think.

```
date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This is working for me in my project. You can check here [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If you store the result in Date variable it will always have the Time part:

```
Dim dt As Date = DateSerial(2015, 5, 1).ToShortDateString
```

If you want to remove time part, you have to use string variable:

```
Dim dtstr As String = DateSerial(2015, 5, 1).ToShortDateString
```

Comment: DateTime has **no** format, it's a binary value like int, decimal, double etc. `ToShortDateString` retuns a *STRING*. Your first line uses VB's implicit conversions to parse this string to a date. The "fix" simply repeats the problematic statement. To control formatting of DateTime values to strings, you should use the proper format strings with `ToString` or `String.Format`

Comment: OK. I used wrong word. Date variable is the correct one. But If you see two lines of code you can find the point.